# E2E testing of Chat based application on different platform

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, appium, skype, saucelabs

I wonder if there is any possibility of testing a chat based application on multiple platforms using automation scripts. Let's say skype, facebook app, etc.

What I understand is that we can automate the app from either of the one side like Android or iOS or Web or  Windows client.
Apparently, I wanted to test the e2e flow on multiple platforms.

My scenarios says as:

```
1.Login in mobile Android client with User A
2.Send message to User B
3.Login in windows client as User B
4.Verify the received message.
```

Is there any way or tool to verify such scenarios?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do that via selenium-webdriver or appium (or some similar tools) first 2 steps of your scenario, second 2 steps on windows you can achieve with [TestComplete](https://smartbear.com/product/testcomplete/overview/). Unfortunately, that's all that came to my mind when you do not have source codes.